# Can someone take a look at my Java code?

Tags: java

So the assignment is to write a `java program` that declares an array alpha of `50 elements` of type `double` using an if statement. Initialize the array so that the first `25` elements are **equal** to the square of the index variable and the last 25 elements are equal to three times the index variable.

This is my code:

```
   int i=0;      
    int count=0;
    double[] alpha= new double [50];

    for (i=0; i<alpha.length; i++)
    { 
    if (alpha.length<25)
    alpha[i]= i*i;

    System.out.print(alpha[i] + " ");

    if (alpha.length>=25)
    alpha[i]= 3*i;      

     System.out.print(alpha[i] + " ");
        count++;
        if (count==10){
        System.out.println("\n");
        count=0;
```

The problem is that i can get the last part of the code to work

```
 if (alpha.length>=25) alpha[i]= 3*i
```

but the first part of the code does not not work.I get an answer of:

`0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 6.0 0.0 9.0 0.0 12.0 0.0 15.0 0.0 18.0 0.0 21.0 0.0 24.0 0.0 27.0 
0.0 30.0 0.0 33.0 0.0 36.0 0.0 39.0 0.0 42.0 0.0 45.0 0.0 48.0 0.0 51.0 0.0 54.0 0.0 57.0 0.0 60.0 0.0 63.0 0.0 66.0 0.0 69.0 0.0 72.0 0.0.`

Can anyone see what is wrong?

Comment: You try to put in a double array integer values...

Comment: you might want it to be **if (i<25)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `alpha.length>=25` is always **TRUE** and `alpha.length < 25` is always **FALSE**, since your `alpha.length` is 50.

Try using the **`index i`** for your comparison.

```
if (i < 25)
 alpha[i] = i * i;
....
....
if (i >= 25)
 alpha[i] = 3 * i;
```

Answer (score 2):

alpha.length will always be greater than 25.   You need to compare i to see if it is less than or greater than 25.

Answer (score 1):

**Alpha length is not changing in FOR iteraton. You'll have to compare i variable!**
    for (i=0; i

```
System.out.print(alpha[i] + " ");

if (i>=25)
alpha[i]= 3*i;      

 System.out.print(alpha[i] + " ");
    count++;
    if (count==10){
    System.out.println("\n");
    count=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`alpha.length` is length of array which will always be equal to 50 .

**Change your condition**

> ```
> if (alpha.length<25)
> ```

**to**

> ```
> if (i<25)
> ```

**Similarly change**

> if (alpha.length>=25)

**to**

> if (i>=25)

Comment: Err! Second condition is still the same.